# find and replace pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with names

```
aaaaxxxdddd
dddxbbb
aaaaxxxcccc
```

I want to say if string contains 'xxx' then replace 'a' with 'b'

giving

```
bbbbxxxdddd
dddxbbb
bbbbxxxcccc
```

I have the 2 bits of code but can't figure out how to put them together

```
if df['col'].str.contains('xxx')
 df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda x: str.replace(x, 'a',"b"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with filtering rows by boolean mask in both size for improve performance - `replace` only for fitered rows:

```
m = df['col'].str.contains('xxx')
df.loc[m, 'col'] = df.loc[m, 'col'].str.replace('a',"b")

print (df)
           col
0  bbbbxxxdddd
1      dddxbbb
2  bbbbxxxcccc
```

Another solution is use `list comprehension`:

```
df['col'] = [x.replace('a',"b") if 'xxx' in x else x for x in df['col']]
```